# checkSelfPermission() for API 22

Tags: android, api

Is there any other argument to use instead of `checkSelfPermission()`. I want to compile my code in API 22. But `checkSelfPermission()` is only support API levels 23 and higher.

Comment: Use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Import package

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
```

**Step 2:** Check permission

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Class.this, new String[]permission},requestCode);
```

**Step 3:** After permission is granted, you can invoke

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult() {
}
```